# Dynamically include a blade template depending on an input value

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new at Laravel and PHP and I'm stuck with this. If there is any other way to do this, either with blade statements or anything else I would appreciate it, since I'd like to avoid to use javascript as much as possible, but I guess that I have no choice if I need to use onChange.

I have a blade template with some inputs that I'd like replicate depending on another input. For example: if I introduce the number 4, I should get 4 times the same set of inputs.

**Inputs (inputs.blade.php)**

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="1">
</div>


<legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0 mt-3">Tags</legend>
@foreach($images as $image)
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="image" id="{{$image->name}}" value="{{$image->name}}:{{$image->version}}">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{$image->name}}">
        {{$image->name}}:{{$image->version}}

    </label>
</div>
@endforeach

<div class="form-check form-switch mb-3">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" name="setFolder" id="setFolder">
  <label class="form-check-label"  for="setFolder">Use a file instead</label>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="" class="form-label">File directory</label>
    <input id="dir" name="dir" type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="2">
</div>
```

**Where I want to include and replicate them (index.blade.php)**

I would like to write something like this, but since I need to use the onChange (at least using the knowledge I possess at the moment) I guess this is completely wrong:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <h1>Create</h1>
    <form action="/activity" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">C versions</legend>
        @foreach($versions as $v)
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="version" id="{{$v->version}}" value="{{$v->version}}:{{$v->engine}}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="{{$v->version}}">
                {{$v->version}}:{{$v->engine}}

            </label>
        </div>
        @endforeach

            <label class="form-check-label mt-3" for="nServices">Number of services</label>
            <input type="number" value="2" min="2" max="999" id="nServices" name="nServices"> 
            @php
                $nServices = Request::input('nServices');
            @endphp
        <div class="mt-3" id="replace">
            @for ($i = 0; $i < $nServices; $i++) 
                @include('inputs') 
            @endfor 
        </div>
```

So instead I did this and added javascript but I can't use blade inside it (again, this is as far as my knowledge reaches)

```
 <label class="form-check-label mt-3" for="nServices">Number of services</label>
            <input type="number" value="2" min="2" max="999" id="nServices" name="nServices"> 
           
        <div class="mt-3" id="replace">
            
        </div>
```

**scripts.js**

```
document.getElementById('nServices').onchange = function () {
    var html = @include('inputs');
    for(var i = 0; i < this.value; i++){
       document.getElementById('replace').append(html);
    }
   
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can use blade in inline javascript

Comment: @brombeer then why does my script not work?

Comment: `scripts.js` doesn't sound like inline script, but an external file. But you could place your javascript inside `<script></script>` in a .blade file and see if that works

Comment: @brombeer Tried and doesn't work, I receive the raw html and I can't turn it into rendered items. I mean, append needs a string. I tried with some php functions and adding " " and I can't convert it

Comment: Refer this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557747/laravel-blade-use-jquery-load-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557747/laravel-blade-use-jquery-load-method) Hope this helps.